# file got corrupted during blob to file conversion (java)

Tags: java, file-upload, netbeans, download

why my download file always got corrupted.

I have a code that will upload file using blob.
the code is 
`InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath)); //the file to  upload
pst.setBinaryStream(15, inputStream); //to upload the selected file`

it's successfully upload to my sql data base but when I try to download it, it always got corrupted.
below is my code to download the file from sql.

```
try
             {
                    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                    String url1 = "jdbc:sqlserver://ets88-spare:1433;databaseName=users;user=sa;password=test";
                    Connection conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection(url1);
                    String query1 = "SELECT * FROM ets_verification";
                    Statement state = conn1.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery(query1);
                    while (rs.next())
                    {        
                        String boardname = jboardName.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        String sn = jserialNumber.getText();
                        String status = jverificationStatus.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        String filename = boardname + "_" + "_" + sn + "_"+ status;
                        byte[] array = rs.getBytes(16);
                         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("c:\\" + filename + ".rar");
                            fos.write(array);
                            fos.close();

                        System.out.println("array:" + array);
                }              
             }
             catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)
             {
                     jnote.setText(e.toString());
                     System.out.println("error" + e.toString());
    }       catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ets_verification.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```

Comment: Have you considered using `getBinaryStream` instead of `getBytes`

Comment: @MadProgrammer I try to use that and also I change the 'byte[]' to 'InputStream' and remove the 'fos.write' and 'fos.close' but still it is corrupted.

Comment: Can you check in DB table, whether the blob is viewable or not. you can right click on the blob and view the image using workbench or heidisql..

Comment: @Desing as per checking  the DB it is convert to 0xFFD8.........
i dont know how to the workbench and hiedisql

Comment: Even null blobs showing this value. Only way to confirm this would br investigate in mysql workbench. You can download it, it is IDE for mysql

Comment: i will try that. hopefully this will fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try.
Tested in a ORACLE DB.

```
(...)
Blob blob = rs.getBlob(16);
if (blob != null) {
    byte[] b = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("PATH/TO/FILE/FILENAME.rar")){
        fos.write(file);
    }catch (IOException ex) {
        //Do something
    }
}
(...)
```